# Is there a maximum length for NOTAM?

Tags: notam

I see some very long NOTAM messages describing a whole section of arrival or departing procedure.

Is there a standard limiting how long a NOTAM can be? In computing I usually see limits in bytes, is there such a limit on NOTAM?

Comment: longest I’ve ever seen was 1.5 pages A5 on very small print, so I guess NO :-(

Comment: The EAA Airventure NOTAM usually runs around 32 pages every year.

Answer (score 2):

According to [an FAA guide to creating NOTAMs](https://www.notams.faa.gov/downloads/ccrguide.pdf) (see pages 14 and 21), the "condition text", i.e. the body of the NOTAM...

> has a max length around 1200 alpha-numeric characters. If necessary,
>   the system will allow a user to create up to ten parts with 1200
>   characters each

But, that doesn't include other parts of the NOTAM, like location, date/time, graphical elements etc. I don't know if there's a limit (in kB?) for the complete NOTAM file or not; the document doesn't seem to mention anything about that. It also isn't clear from the FAA document if the ~12,000 characters is a format limitation/specification, or a tool limitation.